# How do I loop a portfolio return calculation for multiple periods in matlab?

Tags: matlab, loops, finance, portfolio

I have the following data/sets (simplified version to make the example clear):

- `3*10` matrix of stocks identified by a number for a given period (3 stocks (my portfolio) in rows * by 10 days (in columns) named indexBest.
- `10*10` matrix of returns for each period for each security in my universe named dailyret (my universe of stocks is 10).

I want to create a loop where I am able to calculate the sum returns of each portfolio for each period into one matrix ideally `1*10` or `10*1` (returns * date or vice versa).

I have done this for a single period for a portfolio, see below: but I want to be able to automate this process instead of doing all this `10*` over for each portfolio for each period. Please help!

```
Portfolio_1_L= indexBest(:,1); %helps me get the portfolio constituents for period one (3 stocks basically).
Returns_1_L= dailyret(Portfolio_1(:,1));%to calculate returns of the portfolio for period 1 I have referenced  the extraction of returns to the portfolio constituents.
Sum_ret_Port_1_L=sum(Returns_1_L); %sum return of the portfolio for period one
```

How do I loop this process for all other 9 periods?

Answer (score 3):

Use a `for` loop and use the index variable in place of hardcoded `1` in your example code. Also index the output to store the result for each day.

```
for day = 1:10
    Portfolio_1_L = indexBest(:,day);
    Returns_1_L = dailyret(Portfolio_1_L);
    Sum_ret_Port_1_L(day) = sum(Returns_1_L);
end
```

Comment: When i enter the code below for my final soultion in Sum_ret_Port_ the return for first portfolio is correct then second is a weird number and third is the right answer for the what the second should be etc... any idea why?                                                    for day = 1:10

Portfolio_= indexBest(:,:);
Returns_= dailyret(Portfolio_(:,:));
Sum_ret_Port_=sum(Returns_);
end

Comment: You are not using the `day` variable anywhere in your code. You should use it to index into the inputs and output.

Comment: do you  mean luike this? insteda of day i use i here and M=10. But i still dont get the right result... please correct me or clarify....      for i=1:M

Portfolio_= indexBest(i);
Returns_= dailyret(Portfolio_(i));
Sum_ret_Port_=sum(Returns_(i));
end

Comment: Thanks, but when I do this i get the following reply: ??? Attempted to access Portfolio_1_L(:,2); index out of bounds because
size(Portfolio_1_L)=[3,1].

Comment: Thanks again, but the problem still persist: return for first portfolio is correct then second is a weird number and third is the right answer for the what the second should be etc

Comment: Then you better look at your data. You can examine variables in the workspace, or even better, if you are using functions, set breakpoints and step through the code.

Comment: I have fixed it. Thanks for your guidance, there was a slight mistake in your code, otherwise it was perfect. My solution is M=10, period=day thereafter: for period=1:M

Portfolio_ = indexBest(:,period);
Returns_(:,period)= dailyret(Portfolio_,period);
Sum_ret_Port_(period)=sum(Returns_(:,period));
end